# Eclipse build techniques

Tags: java, eclipse, build, dependencies, gradle

I have been using eclipse for quite a while. I have used it with ant, maven and now with gradle. I understand that eclipse build (defaults to `bin` folder) and gradle keeps the built files in `build` (though these folder names can be configured)

I have set of eclipse projects which have dependencies among themselves. Gradle can be clearly instructed by `evaluationDependsOn` in gradle file to make sure that all the dependencies are built before the current project is built

However, when I manually select the projects and execute a clean build (I generally disable `build automatically`) it is not able to resolve the dependencies in the order. But when I see the build-path's project tab of these projects I see the dependencies correctly.

So for now, I visit each project and do a clean build in the specific order to clear all the eclipse errors. I was wondering if I can have a fix for it.

Comment: Gradle will automatically compile projects in the correct order (provided you correctly defined their dependencies). `evaluationDependsOn` has a different function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure it out it is `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Build Order`

Like many times, writing the question in Stackoverflow makes you understand the problem better.

Comment: yeah, than I am deleting my question on which onlyI have answered :)